# Jquery slide out menu

Tags: jquery, menu, jquery-animate

Hi I have a codepen slideout menu. It was working fine and I have it on a couple sites and now it doest seem to be sliding out at all it may be due to the update in jquery? can someone please help me out.

http://codepen.io/mariovass/pen/pFAgG

Answer (score 1):

Delete

```
.navButton:active {
      position:relative;
      top:1px;
    }
```